# Php Put into new array one row of another multidimentional associative array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, row

I have multidimensional associative array returned by a MYSQL table.

```
array { [0]=> array 
                    { 
                        ["id"]=> string(8) "130" 
                        ["name"]=> string(7) "mike" 
                        ["nickname"]=> string(7) "raze" 
                    } 
        [1]=> array
                    { 
                        ["id"]=> string(8) "120" 
                        ["name"]=> string(7) "jimmy" 
                        ["nickname"]=> string(5) "killer" 
                    }
    }
```

I would extract one row into another multidimensional associative array with the same structure.
After this, my new array should be:

```
array { [0]=> array
                { 
                    ["id"]=> string(8) "120" 
                    ["name"]=> string(7) "jimmy" 
                    ["nickname"]=> string(5) "killer" 
                }
}
```

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Any example code for what you have so far, what you have tried?

Comment: Please provide an example of your data.